# check the convergence of this sequence $S_{n}=\frac{1}{\ln(2n+1)}\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{((2i)!)^2}{2^{4i} (i!)^4}.$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I need a **hint** for the evaluating following sequence $(S_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.
$$S_{n}=\frac{1}{\ln(2n+1)}\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{((2i)!)^2}{2^{4i}(i!)^4}.$$
First of all, I see that the whole series by the root series is convergent.

**But I would like to see that the sequence is convergent to what number?**

I just need a hint.

Comment: $(S_n)$ is  sequence, not  a series.

Comment: I think the $n$'s in your sum should be $i$'s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $b_n=\ln(2n+1)$ is a strictly increasing sequence that diverges to $\infty$, you can use [Stolz-Cesaro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem):
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n+1}\frac{((2i)!)^2}{(2^i i!)^4}-\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{((2i)!)^2}{(2^i i!)^4}}{\ln(2n+3)-\ln(2n+1)}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{((2n+2)!)^2}{(2^{n+1}(n+1)!)^4}\frac{1}{\ln\frac{2n+3}{2n+1}} \end{align}$$
Then use Stirling's approximation and $\lim_{t\to 1}\frac{\ln t}{t-1}=1$:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2\pi(2n+2)\left(\frac{2n+2}{e}\right)^{4n+4}}{2^{4n+4}4\pi^2(n+1)^2\left(\frac{n+1}{e}\right)^{4n+4}}\frac{1}{\frac{2n+3}{2n+1}-1}
 $$
Notice that
$$\frac{\left(\frac{2n+2}{e}\right)^{4n+4}}{2^{4n+4}\left(\frac{n+1}{e}\right)^{4n+4}}=1 $$
So
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{4\pi(n+1)^2}=\frac{1}{\pi}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The sum converges to some number $a$ for $n\to\infty$, while you keep on dividing by $\ln(2n+1) \to \infty$, so the limit of $S_n$ is $0$.

Comment: I would love that

Comment: @LukasRollier the summand in sum does not converge to zero. Am I right?

Comment: The summand is equal to $\frac{1}{4^{2i-1}(i!)^2}$, which tends to zero very rapidly

Comment: @HamedBaghalGhaffari. Could you clarify $(2i!)^2$ ? Is it $4(i!)^2$ or $[(2i)!]^2$ ?

Comment: @LukasRollier  what is $a$ for sum? I found it zero. Is that right?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I improved it.

Comment: @HamedBaghalGhaffari, could you also improve the denominator? It is also ambiguous in the same sense

Comment: @LukasRollier WolframAlpha says the sum is divergent. Can you check again? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28%282n%29%21%29%5E2%2F%282%5E%28n%29%28n%21%29%29%5E4+from+0+to+infinity

Comment: Yes, my answer was written in the assumption that $(2i!)^2$ was meant instead of $((2i)!)^2$